# Which framework to make menu based game on for iOS?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, uikit

I apologize if this is a hard/poor question to answer. If it is, please suggest ways of improving it.

My question is basically which framework should I base a menu based game in? The game would be something similar to the Big Win Sports games. All the gameplay is managing, but there would need to be the ability to show AI playing of the sport (no user playing, just simulated gameplay). As for the menus, they would be various menus to do things like change the players, buy players, play games, and view standings.

My initial thought was to make it in SpriteKit because it's a game engine and that's what I have experience with.

After thinking about this for a while longer, I began to think that since there is no real 'game' element other than the simulation, I shouldn't need to use SpriteKit. By that I mean that I don't think there's a need for physics, collisions, or other things that SpriteKit provides. This would lead me to think that I should make the game in UIKit with storyboards.

To make sure that this isn't closed as yan opinion based question, I'll narrow my question down to this. What benefits for a menu based game would the likes of UIKit, SpriteKit, etc. provide to the game I described? Feel free to add in any opinions regarding anything I said.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not both?

SpriteKit can coexist alongside UIKit. An `SKView` is a `UIView` subclass that contains an `SKScene` which handles the SpriteKit content. You can embed this `SKView` alongside any other normal `UIView`s from UIKit.

If the majority of the game is menu-based, I would suggest using UIKit. For the simulation, if you need a more game-like environment later (for particle effects, collision detection, etc), you can always drop in an `SkView`.